# How to create a Logic App resource in Azure when hosting in Docker container

Tags: azure, docker, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-apps

Following on from this question about how to host a standard [Logic App in a Docker container in App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977147/http-call-to-logic-app-in-a-docker-container). I have started down the same path based on [the tip provided here](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip311.html) but am hitting a wall when trying to create the metadata about the logic app in the Azure portal.

The Logic App create flow in the portal offers two hosting options - **workflow** and **docker container**. Workflow offers one of the custom app service plans for workflow and doesn't allow selection of an existing app service.

The docker container choice invites you to select a Region, stating that

> Docker containers are only supported with custom locations. In order to run from a Docker container, either create a new custom location or switch to a subscription which already has one.

While the messaging is unclear here, it seems that this requires a container app environment, meaning this choice targets the preview for container apps. ***(edit: I created a container app and it didn't show up as an option as a custom region, so I'm still not sure what that is)***

I'd like to leverage an existing app service plan to host my docker-contained Logic App workflow, but I'm unclear how to create a resource in Azure which would represent that Logic App. Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think you can re-use existing app service as app service for logic app have some differences compared to normal app services. Custom location referred to azure enable arc location for kubernetes.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for that info on regions. The sales pitch for LA standard includes the ability to host anywhere functions can be hosted, including in a docket container. That’s supported by app service. Maybe it’ll work per that hint article but not have a management interface